# PyMongo subtract dates

Tags: pymongo

I have this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM journal
        WHERE extract('day' FROM (current_date - last_update)) >= update_frequency LIMIT :limit;
```

I want to make similar query on mongo. I tried this query but it doesn't work

```
db.journal.find( { "$gt": [{ "$subtract": [ datetime.today(), "$last_update" ]}, "$update_frequency" ]} ).count()
```

Document structure

```
{'_id': ObjectId('609156acbe97a0dbab0e3673'),
 'title': 'BMJ-BRITISH MEDICAL JOURNAL',
 'publisher': ObjectId('60915569be97a0dbab0e30e0'),
 'tag': [ObjectId('60913bb849c75c8fc32339a5')],
 'IF': '1',
 'journal_link': 'https://journals.bmj.com/',
 'rss_link': 'http://ard.bmj.com/pages/rss-feeds/',
 'last_update': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 'update_frequency': 3,
 'journal_id': 1}
```

Comment: Can you also describe the logic you want to perform on your document?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for using an aggregation query.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  "$$NOW",  // Replace with `datetime.now()` if required
                  "$last_update"
                ]
              },
              86400000
            ]
          },
          "$update_frequency"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```